# How To Install Ffmpeg with libfaac, libx264, libavfilter with QT-FastStart

Tags: centos, ffmpeg

I am working to install kernel video sharing script. They are not supporting me setting up my VPS correctly so I am facing problems setting it up. The problem is that I have to install Ffmpeg with libfaac, libx264, libavfilter and QT-FastStart. I can't get a proper guide on this.

I am using Centos 6.4 x32bit.

I have already found this one.

http://www.alduccino.com/installing-ffmppeg-flvtool2-and-yamdi-on-centos-6

but after performing all the steps I use

```
whereis ffmpeg
```

command and it does not give provide me with location which I guess means that it is not properly installed.

The second guide I found is

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CentosCompilationGuide

in this guide there is no way told to install libavfilter and libfaac. I need them both.

Can anybody, help me regarding this? I also need qt faststart to be installed which is automatically installed using the first guide but I dont know about second.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you need libfaac? libfdk_aac, which the guide on the ffmpeg wiki will install, is vastly superior; the only reason you should need libfaac is if you need to redistribute your ffmpeg binary. When I installed ffmpeg from the equivalent Ubuntu compilation guide, I got all the filters by default, without having to do anything else. Also, ffmpeg can do qt-faststart's job with `-movflags faststart`.

Comment: According to these server requirements I guess I need them. http://www.kernel-video-sharing.com/en/requirements/

Comment: @evilsoup Both libfaac and fdk-aac require `--enable-nonfree` resulting in a non-redistributable binary.

Comment: To compile `qt-faststart`: follow the second guide then run: `cd ~/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/tools && make qt-faststart`. You can then move the resulting binary to a location that will work with your product. faac is not easy to compile. Install fdk-aac and edit the scripts to use it instead.